# Looping: with different row number in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, loops

I wonder if you could give me a hint on how to get over the problem I encountered when trying to extract data from HTML files. I looked through other questions regarding the issue but still cannot figure out what changes exactly should I make. I have five HTML files in a folder. From each of them, I want to extract HTML links which I will later use. First, I extracted this data without any effort reading every HTML separately and creating a separate data frame for each HTML with much-needed links (/item.asp?id=). Then I used a 'rbind' function to merge columns from each data frame. The key here is that the first three HTML pages have 20 rows of the data I need, the fourth HTML has 16 rows, and the fifth and the last has 9 rows.

The looping code works just fine when I loop over the first three pages for which I have 20 rows each, but the code doesn't allow me to do the same for the fourth and fifth HTML pages because there the row number is different. I get the problem:
`Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, i, value = c("/item.asp?id=22529120",  : replacement has 16 rows, data has 20`
The code is as follows:

```
#LOOP over others
path = "C:/Users/Dasha/Downloads/R STUDIO/RECTORS/test retrieve"
out.file<-""
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".html")

for (i in 1:length(file.names))
{
  page <- read_html(file.names[i])
  links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
##get all links into a dataframe
  df <-as.data.frame(links) 
##get links which contain /item.asp
  page_article <- df[grep("/item.asp", df$links), ] 
##for each HTML save a separate data frame with links column
  java[i] <-as.data.frame(page_article) 
##save number of a page where this link is
  page_num[i] <- paste(toString(i)) 
##save id of a person this page belongs to
  id[i] <- as.character(file.names[i]) 
  
}
```

Can anyone give a bit of advice on how to solve this issue? If I am successful, I then must be capable to create a single column with links, another column with an id and a number of the HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function which returns a dataframe after reading from each HTML file.

```
read_html_files <- function(filename) {
  page <- read_html(filename)
  links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
  page_article <- grep("/item.asp", links, value = TRUE)
  data.frame(filename, page_article)
}
```

Use `purrr::map_df` and pass this function to every file and combine the output in one dataframe (`result`).

```
path = "C:/Users/Dasha/Downloads/R STUDIO/RECTORS/test retrieve"
file.names <- list.files(path, pattern ="\\.html$", full.names = TRUE)
result <- purrr::map_df(file.names, read_html_files, .id = 'id')
result
```